# Can't get RazorEngine to work with asp core DI container

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razorengine

I am hoping to get an IViewLocalizer working with RazorEngine. I tried to follow the guide and some questions on SO.

So far I have:

```
//Razor engine config in Startup.cs

var config = new FluentTemplateServiceConfiguration(c =>
{
    c.WithBaseTemplateType(typeof(MvcTemplateBase<>));
    c.ActivateUsing((ctx) => 
        (ITemplate)services.BuildServiceProvider().GetRequiredService(ctx.TemplateType)
    );                
});

var razorEngine = RazorEngineService.Create(config);

services.AddSingleton(razorEngine);
```

I know for a fact that my ILocalizer is registered properly as a service, I can use it outside of RazorEngine without issue.

My `TemplateBase<T>` implementation is:

```
public abstract class MvcTemplateBase<T> : TemplateBase<T>
{
    public MvcTemplateBase(IViewLocalizer localizer)
    {
        Html = new HtmlHelper();
        Json = new JsonHelper();
        Localizer = localizer;
    }

    public HtmlHelper Html { get; set; }
    public JsonHelper Json { get; set; }
    public IViewLocalizer Localizer { get; set; }
}
```

Unfortunately, when I try to generate a template:

> - error: (10, 19) There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'localizer' of
>     'MvcTemplateBase.MvcTemplateBase(IViewLocalizer)'

So it looks like the `MvcTemplateBase<T>` is not being instantiated through DI.

Also, along with the above error, I also get:

> - error: (15, 18) The name 'inject' does not exist in the current context
> - error: (17, 18) The name 'model' does not exist in the current context
> - error: (19, 18) The name 'section' does not exist in the current context
> - error: (29, 4) The name 'ViewData' does not exist in the current context

It almost seems like it's using a `TemplateBase<T>` that has none of the basic properties you would expect. AFAIK RazorEngine should support `@model` right out of the box.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure, but you are creating a root service provider and perhaps you have to create a scoped service provider.

Comment: @Silvermind Sorry, I'm not very familiar with DI. What is a root/scoped service provider?

Comment: `services.BuildServiceProvider()` returns `IServiceProvider` which has a method `CreateScope()` which returns a scoped service provider. Also worth checking is if the fluent api delegate is executed before you add your services, because all services added after that will be missing then.

Comment: @Silvermind Oh thanks! Yes the fluent configuration appears after all services have been added. I'll try with the scoped provider. Thanks!

Comment: @Matthew Goulart Did you ever solve this, I have exactly the same problem.

Comment: @DanCook no sorry, I gave up and then tried again a month later and still couldn't get it to work.